# Flutter, one project for Mobile and web

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, frontend

Can I use one Flutter project to create web and mobile applications? if yes, How will I go about it, since some libraries that work with mobile might not work with the web? And how can I build a project such that the web pages do not fall into the production mobile app.

Comment: You can use [Platform](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-io/Platform-class.html) to check the host target type and decide use relative libraries or not in your coding

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can but the question is ***should you***? as flutter is now capable to support multiple platforms with a single code base. but the problem arises when you have to implement some complex functionalities into it and there are few packages that support all platforms that you want to deploy. So to tackle this either you have to ditch the idea to implement those functionalities or write your own package.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to limit your project to only the web platform or the mobile platform when building the project. Also, you can choose not to use any external library in your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the platform that your app is run you can use the class [Platform](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-platform_platform/Platform-class.html).

But be careful this class can be problematic for web so you should you [kisweb](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/kIsWeb-constant.html)

```
if (kisweb) {
  // you're on web
}
```